# Is it possible to create a Windows group policy in reverse?

Tags: windows, windows-10, script, windows-registry, group-policy

Is it possible to create a group policy in "reverse" based upon the current registry state?

I do a lot of Windows 10 customizing via registry, preferring this to fishing around in group policy lists, given it's my own purely local machine and I also like knowing exactly what and where settings/tweaks are acting upon; "command line" style vs. "GUI", so to speak.

Having put off a dreaded reinstall specifically because of the ordeal in setting everything up again, I had the realization how much easier this would be had I been customizing via group policy all along, easily and simply able to reapply the policy after reinstalling.

I'll start doing this going forward, but for now, is there any way to create a group policy in reverse based on the current state of registry endpoints that such policies would alter?

Comment: Pretty sure this doesnt exist. If you kept track of which registry hacks you applied, you can use https://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/ to look up the equivalent GPO.

Comment: @Silbee Dang. Unfortunately, I haven't kept track of what I've applied, I just do them as I go along. Are there any reasons or roadblocks that would prevent a tool such as this from working? I think maybe I'll try to make this myself, unless there'd be some technical roadblock I'm not aware of. Also, thanks for the link, looks like a cool tool.

Comment: Here are some problems i see of the bat: Your program would have to be aware of all possible keys and their default values, otherwise it cannot know if a value was changed. Programs create their own keys, its impossible to keep track of them all. Was a key/value changed by the user as a tweak or was it changed due to the installation of another program that is needed to support this key/value pair. etc... I'm afraid its an impossible task.

Comment: @Silbee I realize it wouldn't be easy or perfect. My loose idea is automating a script to crawl over a fresh group policy, changing each individual policy line item, one by one, while I monitor the backend watching which registry keys get touched/changed. Afterward, I'd be left with a rough index of everywhere in the registry group policy interacts with. I'd then export that list of keys from my machine, and then reverse-engineer packing that list into a group policy .POL file. Could that work?

Comment: That would absolutely work, its just a big task :) Good luck, i hope you can get most of your tweaks exported ! Mind you, lists like the one you wish to create yourself by crawling over gpo's already exist. For example https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250 is a spreadsheet file containing all Administrative template GPO's and their corresponding keys.